# reduce ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabhost

I want to put an image on a TAB, and I need to be smaller. I tried so, but the image does not change the size.

```
ImageView image1 = new ImageView(this);
image1.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.book));
image1.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
image1.setMaxWidth(10);
image1.setMaxHeight(10);

tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 1").setContent(R.id.tab1).setIndicator(image1));
```

to set the image of a tab can refer to an xml tag in `main.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the layout height and layout width

using the following code:

```
image1.getLayoutParams().width = 10;
image1.getLayoutParams().height = 10;
```